# Conditional distributions of two mutually dependent binomial random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

If $X,Y$ are *mutually dependent* binomial random variables, do we know how $Y|X$ and $X|Y$ are distributed?

$X,Y$ are the sum of $n$ iid Bernoulli variables,
\begin{align}
X&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i, \qquad &X_i \sim Bin(1, P(X_i=1)) \\ 
Y&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i, \qquad &Y_i \sim Bin(1, P(Y_i=1)).
\end{align}

Wikipedia has a section on [conditional binomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Related_distributions), which roughly states:

*Take all realizations of $X_i$, which equal $1$ with probability $P(X_i=1)$. Whenever $\{X_i=1\}$, take all realizations of $Y_i$ which equal $1$ with probability $P(Y_i=1|X_i=1)$. Then, $Y$ is binomial with probability $P(Y_i=1)=P(Y_i=1|X_i=1)P(X_i=1)$.*

But this seems to hold only if $P(Y_i=1|X_i=0)=0$, since the law of total probability states
\begin{equation}
P(Y_i=1)=P(Y_i=1|X_i=1)P(X_i=1)+P(Y_i=1|X_i=0)P(X_i=0).
\end{equation}

Conversely, the sum of $n$ independent but *not identically distributed* (i.e. different probabilities) Bernoulli trials has a [Poisson-binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). So my intuition says that if you sum those $Y_i$ where $\{X_i=1\}$ with those where $\{X_i=0\}$, you shouldn't get a binomial distribution since you are summing Bernoulli variables with different probabilities. Thus, if $Y$ is binomially distributed, $Y|X$ cannot be binomially distributed.